# How can I make the height of the div dynamically fit the size of the div in which it is contained?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular js to show the information in my view

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     <div style="height: 140px; width: 7px; float: left; margin-right: 20px"
          ng-style="{'background-color': activity.category.color}">
     </div>
     <h4 style="word-wrap: break-word"><strong>{{ activity.name }}</strong>
     </h4>
     <p><strong>Salón:</strong> {{ activity.place.name }}</p>
     <p>{{ activity.begin_date | date: 'h:mma' }} - {{ activity.end_date | date: 'h:mma' }}</p>
     <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> {{ activity.end_date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
     <p id="{{ activity.id }}_description" class="collapse"
        style="word-wrap: break-word">{{ activity.description }}</p>
</div>
```

But I have a problem, when the name of the activity is very long, the left red bar does not fit the size of the div in which it is contained, this causes my activity data to move to the left

Error:

[image]

How can I make the height of the div dynamically fit the size of the div in which it is contained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead adding a `DIV` with `float` add border to your outer `DIV` like below.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="col-md-10" style="border:0;border-left:7px solid;border-color:red;">
      
      <h4 style="display:block; "><strong>Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name </strong></h4>
      <p><strong>Salón:</strong> Place Name</p>
      <p>00:24 AM - 00:50 PM</p>
      <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> 23-Mar-2019</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` to have content side-by-side. This avoids the usage of `floats` and setting the `height`

```css
.has-activity {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 has-activity">
  <div style="width: 7px; margin-right: 20px;background: red;" class="red"></div>
  <div>
    <h4 style="word-wrap: break-word"><strong>{{ activity.name }}</strong></h4>
    <p><strong>Salón:</strong> {{ activity.place.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ activity.begin_date | date: 'h:mma' }} - {{ activity.end_date | date: 'h:mma' }}</p>
    <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> {{ activity.end_date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
    <p id="{{ activity.id }}_description" class="collapse" style="word-wrap: break-word">{{ activity.description }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Bootstrap**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row m-4">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class=" d-flex">
      <div style="width: 7px; margin-right: 20px;background: red;" class="red"></div>
      <div>
        <h4 style="word-wrap: break-word"><strong>{{ activity.name }}</strong></h4>
        <p><strong>Salón:</strong> {{ activity.place.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ activity.begin_date | date: 'h:mma' }} - {{ activity.end_date | date: 'h:mma' }}</p>
        <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> {{ activity.end_date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
        <p id="{{ activity.id }}_description" class="collapse" style="word-wrap: break-word">{{ activity.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on run code snippet to see how it works. I've added 2 snippets

### 1. Overflow hidden

You can hide the overflowing content using max-width: 100% and overflow: hidden property. As shown below.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1><u>Updated</u></h1>
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div style="height: 140px; width: 7px; float: left; margin-right: 20px; background-color: red"></div>
  <h4 style="display:block; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap"><strong>Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name </strong></h4>
  <p><strong>Salón:</strong> Place Name</p>
  <p>00:24 AM - 00:50 PM</p>
  <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> 23-Mar-2019</p>
</div>
```

### 2. Bonus: ellipsis

You can also add text-overflow: ellipsis for showing an ellipsis at the end of the text if it overflows

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1><u>Bonus</u></h1>
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div style="height: 140px; width: 7px; float: left; margin-right: 20px; background-color: red"></div>
  <h4 style="display:block; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis"><strong>Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name Activity Name </strong></h4>
  <p><strong>Salón:</strong> Place Name</p>
  <p>00:24 AM - 00:50 PM</p>
  <p><strong>Fecha de terminación:</strong> 23-Mar-2019</p>
</div>
```